# passing json as parameter in return view

Tags: javascript, json, laravel, view, laravel-blade

I have a controller with a form() method, this method is called in my route to show a form to user.
In this form I have some script to decide fields to be displayed to user. This decision is based on informations from controller.

Important information:
My json can have an array structure or single structure, like this:

```
object = {"errorMessage":"message", 
          "profile":profile list (array) || null (single),
          "listActivities": acitivitie list (array) || null (single)
         }
```

My problem is that I can't send a json from controller to view, I have tried some ways, as bellow:

First Try:

```
return view("bladename","objectName",$myObject)
```

in my view

```
var teste = {!! objectName !!}
or
var teste = {{ objectName }}
```

Second Try:

```
return view("bladename")->with("objectName",$myObject);
```

with same js of first try

In both cases occurs error

In the last attempt I did the following:

```
$jsonOutput = json_encode($myObjetc);
return view("bladename","objectName",$myObject)
```

but in the view, `"` are replaced for &quote.

In few words, I need send a json object from controller calling a blade and receive as JavaScript in the view.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$jsonOutput = json_encode($myObjetc);
return view('bladename')->with('jsonOutput',$jsonOutput);
```

In your view

```
var teste = {{jsonOutput}}
```